# jQuery-File-Upload blueimp PHP-MySQL-database-update data

Tags: php, database, sql-update, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

how to make changes to the data 'title' and 'description' after the image is loaded, for example, add a button to "change"?

This is all done up and running
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-MySQL-database-integration

Here is my code, but here it is necessary to make a new method to "upgrade" and synchronize it with html:

html:

```
name <br /><input name="title[]" value="{%=file.title||''%}">
description<br /> <input name="description[]" value="{%=file.description||''%}">
```

php:

```
public function update($print_response = true) {
    $response = parent::update(false);
    foreach ($response as $name => $update) {
        if ($update) {
            $sql = 'update set  `title`=? ,`description`=? ' 
                .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=?';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param('sss',$file->title,$file->description, $name);
            $query->execute();
        }
    } 
    return $this->generate_response($response, $print_response);
}
```

JS?

Comment: Are you using ASP (`{%`)?

Comment: ASP / PHP ? No such php script on your HTML

Comment: `{% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}><span>delete</span>
                </button><button class="btn btn-primary start" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}">                  
                    <span>update</span>
                </button>`

Comment: Sorry not good in English and in programming, it's just my hobby.